# new Date() format on frontend is different than new Date() on backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

So I got a webapp where users can buy a 'One day access' to the application. The idea is that when the users buys, I update the user with a `endDate` property. Upon login, I'll check if the value in endDate has passed. My model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
    },
});
```

Now, the strange thing is, on my frontend (and also the online sandboxes like JSFidlle & Playcode.io and so on), the following code gives me the date of tomorrow in the following format:

*Format:*
`Thu Feb 06 2020 11:23:06 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

*Code:*

```
let day = new Date();
let nextDay = new Date(day);
nextDay.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);

console.log(nextDay);
```

With the exact same code on my backend, the result of the date is in a completely different format:

*Format:*
`"2020-02-06T10:12:25.559Z"`

*Code:*

```
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    let day = new Date();
    let nextDay = new Date(day);
    nextDay.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);
    res.send(nextDay)
})
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to make the format look the same? Am I missing something?

Comment: You leave it to `console.log` to decide how to turn your date into a string representation. One is using `toString`, while the other shows it in ISO format (UTC). Instead use one of the Date methods to turn it explicitly to a string representation. Then, also take into account locale differences (like timezone or date formats) between server and client.

Comment: This is why you should not rely on `toString` for dates. It depends on the locale set on the device it's run on. You should try to log using `toISOString()` or `toGMTString()
`

Comment: @Seblor [`toGMTString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks guys. Didn't know there were different ways to make a date into a string representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for differences:**
When the data is being sent from the back-end, it is sent as a stringified JSON. This the reason why you get a ISO string instead of Date Object.

**Solution**
You can take the ISO string and parse it using *New Date(string)* again in the frontend code to view at as the same way you want to.

Other way around is to use a npm module known as [serialize-javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript) to send it as an Object instead of a stringified JSON.